# Converting equations to truth tables

Tags: truthtable

I was hoping someone could shed some light on the following equations to be converted to truth tables.
 (A + B)' = A'B'

and

(X')' = X

My question is, how do you handle the inverted sign outside of the brackets?

Especially in the second example, the X' is already inverted, now theres the sign outside of the brackets?
There are only 2 variables, so 2 columns, does the extra ' change this?